# How to generate a random variable from two different distributions in R

Tags: r, distribution

Suppose a random variable Z is taken randomly from two different distributions with equal probability: a standard N(0,1) and an exponential exp(1) with rate=1. I want to generate the random variable Z. 
So in r, my approach is:  Z=0.5X+0.5Y, so Z is from the joint distribution of N(0,1) and exp(1). The r code will be:

`x<-rnorm(1)
 y<-rexp(1)
 z<-0.5x+0.5y`

My question is can I obtain Z by just adding up x and y with their probabilities, or I have to consider the correlations between variables ?

Comment: This may fit better at [stats.se]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. You need another variable U, which is a Bernoulli random variable with p=0.5 and independent of X and Y. Define Z = U*X+(1-U)*Y. In R, you can do

```
x<-rnorm(1)
y<-rexp(1)
u<-rbinom(1,1,0.5)
z<-u*x+(1-u)*y
```

Averaging X and Y results in totally different distribution, not the mixture of distributions you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am confused that, by definition, the binomial distribution is a frequency distribution where there are only two outcomes possible in a given trial. Then if we create a binomial random variable, U will be either 0 or 1, then 1-U will be either 1 or 0, then z will be either normal or exponential random variable. But why can't we obtain a mixture distribution of normal and exponential ?

Comment: Since U is 0/1 with p=0.5, Z is from normal with p=0.5 and exponential with p=0.5, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !  I think I understand now.